# Installed wordpress into the root of an existing wordpress installation

Tags: wordpress

So I made an error in installing a fresh version of wordpress (for domain 2) into the root folder where there is already an existing wordpress installation (domain 1). I've managed to get the original wordpress installation working again (domain 1) but I'm having trouble removing the unwanted installation. When I use GoDaddy's uninstaller it removes files needed by my existing wordpress installation (domain 1).

What can I do to remove the unwanted wordpress installation so that it doesn't show up in GoDaddy as installed for domain 2? The end goal is to properly install wordpress for domain 2 into a different directory.

Let me know if you need any more clarification.

Thank you.

**It's been solved** - when I removed the wordpress installation it took the unnecessary files with it, after a back-up was restored I was able to install wordpress on domain 2 in the correct subdirectory. It seems that GoDaddy was looking at the database file to gauge whether wordpress was installed for a certain domain already.

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Go to Cpanel -> file manager and remove the unwanted files.

Comment: How can I define which files are to do purely with the unwanted installation though? What exactly is the GoDaddy backend looking at when it says that wordpress is already installed for domain 2?

Comment: In the WordPress directory you can find wp-config  file, just rename the file and check the website working fine or not. If the website shows wordpress installation option then you can find the correct file directory each website.

Answer (score 0):

You can use FileZilla FTP Client to remove the unwanted installation ..
after removing it, use FileZilla as well to upload it to another directory .. 
if things are totally missing up, try a Fiverr Gig which can do it for you for a few bucks.